# CompletableFuture - how do i trigger an exception?

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

This is my code :

```
public void deletevendor(VendorEntity vendorEntity) throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            dwService.deleteVendor(vendorEntity);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.info("Error occurred ", ex);
        }
    });
    Boolean isCancelled = future.isCancelled();
    Boolean isDone = future.isDone();
    Boolean isCompletedExceptionally = future.isCompletedExceptionally();

    System.out.println("Asynchronous CompletableFuture: " + isCancelled +" "+ isDone+" "+ isCompletedExceptionally );
}
```

My code inside the try block works fine. I want to trigger the catch block. How can i do that. What could be the inputs that can trigger the exception for my completablefuture?

Comment: Depends entirely on `dwService.deleteVendor`.

Comment: You want to trigger the execution of a `catch` block of a `try { … } catch (Exception ex) { … }` construct, ok. But what’s the relevance of the surrounding `CompletableFuture` stuff?

Comment: Note that if y handle the exceptions inside the lambda that you pass to `runAsync()`, then your future will never be completed exceptionally, except if you cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

For sake of experiments with `Future` this is the way you can trigger the `catch` clause:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    try {
        throw new Exception("");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.info("Error occurred ", ex);
    }
});
```

According to your code snippet, as already said, the entire exception throwing logic is inside calling the `dwService.deleteVendor(vendorEntity)` method. It means you have to pass a specific `vendorEntity` into this `public void deletevendor(VendorEntity vendorEntity)` method in order to throw an exception caught in `CompletableFuture`.